# text area like FCK editor

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to develop a html editor just like FCKeditor, but i dont know how they display the html code in text area like region, Will U pls help me with that? for having that textarea, which prase html codes and displays just like a web page?

Comment: FCK is open source. Why not look through the source code and figure it out?

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, which will be painful, why not just use CKEditor, if it suits your needs ?

Comment: yep, or TinyMCE or indeed any one of the existing solutions

Comment: @Pascal: Instead of re-inventing the wheel AGAIN...

Comment: I'm using jHTMLArea at the moment in conjunction with jQuery, and for a lightweight system it is pretty good. Unfortunately, it does fall short when pasting from Word, as do most WYSIWYG editors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [designMode and contentEditable](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable) elements.

Comment: thanks Dear friends, but its just a part of my College project, so that I can use the already existing one,